# Formula with Multiple Tables in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, sumifs

This is my first post to stack overflow. I've gotten a lot of help from you all over the years by reading others' questions, but I've finally found one I can't find an answer to.

This seems like a relatively straightforward question, but how would I find the average cost of Fruit (cell B15) from the spreadsheet shown in the screenshot without modifying the two tables in any way?

Unfortunately, I can't post an image (bc no reputation) so I'll describe it here:

Two tables:

```
Table 1 (A1:B5): 
Column A = Products (Apple, Celery, Lemon, Carrot);
Column B = Type (Fruit, Vegetable, Fruit, Vegetable

Table 2 (A7:B11):
Column A = Products (Apple, Celery, Lemon, Carrot);
Column B = Cost ($0.45, $0.60, $0.72, $0.86)

B14: "Fruit" <--What I want to find the average price of;

B15: Where the formula will go
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the average cost of fruits that appear in Table 1, and that Table 2 contains the master list of all fruits?

Comment: Yes. Table one lists four "products", two of each type (fruit and vegetable). Table two lists the prices of all of these products listed in table 1. It perhaps would have been more meaningful if I put a quantity column in Table 1 as well, but let's just assume they're all quantity 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell B15 enter this formula:

```
=SUM(IF((B2:B5="fruit"),INDEX(B8:B11,N(IF(1,MATCH(A2:A5,A8:A11,))))))/SUM(IF(B2:B5="fruit",1))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Fabulous. Thank you Excel Hero :) ...not that I have a clue what this formula is doing...

Answer (score -1):

Also consider the =SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range]) function.  It might do just what you need in one simple statement.